# How to restart UIRefreshControl animation?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have several tableviews in a tab bar controller. On some of these I have set a UIRefreshControl.

After swiping down to start a refresh the 'spinner' animation begins. If I select a different tab and then move back to the original tab, the refresh control is still shown but the animation has stopped.

How do I restart this animation?

I've tried starting the refresh again and got no results.
I also inspected the view hierarchy, hoping to find a UIActivityIndicatorView but could only find a `_UIRefreshControlModernReplicatorView` that seems to be the view doing the animation. I don't know of any method I can call of this to get the animation restarted.

Comment: It's a known problem with refresh controllers. Easily reproducible on Apple's own software, such as Mail.

Comment: ah, thanks @LeoNatan I'll leave this up in-case a solution ever becomes available

Comment: I've been trying to hack this myself also. If I come up with something, I'll let you know.

Comment: Did you try calling `[_refreshControl beginRefreshing];` function?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, although not exactly the same problem as described in the original question.

The issue: When I moved from a screen with a tableView with refresh control (not a UITableViewController) to a different one, then I found when I returned to the screen, the activity indicator portion of the refresh control was displaying (not animating) as an artifact just under the top of the table view.

I tried a lot of ideas (hiding the refresh control, ensuring endRefreshing was called, etc.) until I found something that actually worked:

In `viewWillAppear(animated:)`, add the following:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    tableView.refreshControl = nil
    tableView.refreshControl = refresher
}
```

Just adding that code fixed the issue for me. Your mileage may vary, but perhaps somebody will find this useful.